# Django Cache Per View - Different For Every User

Tags: django, caching, django-views, memcached

I'd like to cache a view in my Django app. However, the result of the view varies for every user, so the cache should show a different result to each user.

I've tried using vary_on_cookie, but I can't get it to work:

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
@vary_on_cookie
def my_view(request):
   ...
```

Is there a better way to do this?

P.S. I'm currently using a local, file-based cache for testing, but will eventually use Memcached.

My middleware looks like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',

'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your `CACHES` settings look like? Try to reorder your middleware entry as the Django docs says clearly: _No, that’s not a typo: the “update” middleware must be first in the list, and the “fetch” middleware must be last. The details are a bit obscure, but see Order of MIDDLEWARE below if you’d like the full story._

Comment: My caches looks like this:

CACHES = {
    'default': {

        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': 'C:/...',
    }
}

Comment: @Marco - should the update and fetch middleware go first and last of EVERYTHING else?

Comment: In general, adding those entries into the MIDDLEWARE settings will activate caching for the [whole site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache). But then you need to add also CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS, CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS and CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX to your settings.
To check if it works correctly in your view, I suggest removing the cache entries in your middleware.

Comment: did you solve this? I am using my per site caching, it shows the cached results of user one to user two :/